# Xcode 4.5 // import CoreLocation shows: Expected ';' after method prototype

Tags: core-location, xcode4.5

After download the latest version of the Xcode 4.5 I receive the next trouble.

We use the CoreLocation library, but the when we try to build the project it fails because found the next error:

Parse Issue: `"Expected ';' after method prototype" at CLLocationManager.h`

In this method:

```
- (void)allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:(CLLocationDistance)distance
                      timeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_6_0);
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: same problem here. Any solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I evaluated the configuration of the project, with a new Xcode 4.5 project ... without success ... trying to apply the same compiler conditions and so on ...

The next step was trying to make the code compliant with the iOS 6 specs (solving deprecated code) and converting the code to the ARC requirements

And, after a couple of hours of frustrating work ... I decided to unblock the file CoreLocation.h on the library directory and comment the method.

I now that is not the solution, but I didn't found any other solution. If anybody has been found any other possibility please ... let me know

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for me:

I installed iOS SDK 5.1 on Xcode 4.5.

Check it here: [How can I add older version of iOS SDK in Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602392/ios-5-sdk-is-gone-after-upgrade-to-xcode-4-5)

And it worked for me..