# XCode missing some iOS debug symbols

Tags: ios, debug-symbols, xcode4.6

I am collecting crash logs for my app but sometimes I have a problem where I can't decode the CoreFoundation and other SDK related Symbols. The lines that are from my app I can read so I have no problem there, but it seems that I can't read the Apple symbols unless they came from a build of iOS that I at one point had on my phone. This is a problem because with iOS 6 it seems that there are a few different builds out there depending on which device you have and I skipped the 6.0.x updates and went right to 6.1.2.

How can I get all these symbols without tracking down friends with different iOS versions and plugging their phone in with XCode running so it will extract the symbols? There must be an easier way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other way, which doesn't work for all iOS versions especially not the last bug fix versions, is answered here: [Xcode software image for user iOS in order to symbolicate iOS calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941773/xcode-software-image-for-user-ios-in-order-to-symbolicate-ios-calls/14947156#14947156)

Comment: I will accept your answer because it seems like the link confirms this. I wish it wasn't the answer lol but its a start.