# how to prevent xcode5 from switching over to ios7 layout

Tags: iphone, user-interface, ios7, xcode5

Is it possible to have xcode5 preserve my ios6 project ? I was told it might be possible but i cant get it to work.

Whenever I use my ios6 project on xcode5, the whole UI layout gets messed up because of the topbar. Only way to solve this is to use another laptop with xcode 4.6 on my ios7 device.

The question is how can I run my ios6 project on xcode5 without wanting it to convert into ios7 layout/sdk ?

Thanks.

Comment: Same concept, previous Xcode version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602392/ios-5-sdk-is-gone-after-upgrade-to-xcode-4-5

Answer (score 1):

Open the project file on Xcode 5. Then:

Open file inspector for each xib
On "Interface Builder Documents" section change "Open with" to Xcode 4.6 (if it's 5.0). and "View As" to iOS 6 or earlier

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still cant do it. Even if I set all the xibs to opens in:xcode 4.6 view as: ios6.1 or earlier, it will still show the same ios7 layout. Is there a setting where it will not automatically convert to xcode 5.0 ?

Comment: Still was not able to do it. Even if I change all the xibs and storyboard to 4.6, when i run it, it still shows. Only way is to probably use xcode 4.6 entirely to maintain the project, which kinda suck anyway. Something is just not right and unexplained properly