# Set old deployment Xcode5

Tags: ios, uikit, xcode5

In Xcode 5, when I start a **new** project, how can I set the deployment target and API support for iOS 4?

I want to support the iPhone 3G with a new project. Do I need to set architecture to Arm11?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Not 100% sure, but as far as I know support for iOS 4.2.1 was dropped with Xcode 4.5. So you probably need to use Xcode 4.4 or even older to develop for iOS 4.2.1. And I'm not sure whether you can get that App in the AppStore then, because Apple requires all new Apps to be compatible with iPhone 5. So the old Xcode versions probably do not support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the deployment target dropdown in your projects target:

[image: Deployment Info]

Comment: Ok I got the list to show like yours by adding armv6 to the architectures and removing 64 bit references, how can I support iOS 4.2.1?

Comment: Good question. I guess you have to set Build Active Architecture Only to NO in the Architecture section. Let me know if this worked...

Comment: Apparently it can't be done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463195/xcode-4-5-and-ios-4-2-1-incompatibility

Comment: Maybe you can try to download an older sdk... (refering to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12602603/2798777)